# Por que o script window.open não funciona com o comando "no"?

Tags: javascript, script

Eu percebi que funciona trocar o comando "no" por "yes" no script window.open. Porém, parece que "no" e "0" não são interpretados de jeito nenhum. Já tentei colocar "hidden" e nada também. O que eu posso fazer para solucionar o problema? Não gostaria que a janela abrisse com a barra de endereço nem que a janela fosse redimensionável. Estou postando o código que estou usando. Agradeço muito quem puder me ajudar.

```
<script>
        function openWindow() {
           window.open("banner", "_blank", "location=no,resizable=no,width=700px,height=421px");
        }
        var timer = setTimeout("openWindow()", 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não são todos os navegadores que suportam os recursos do [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Por exemplo, o `resizable=no` e o `location=no` só vão funcionar no IE. Alguns navegadores em versões anteriores (como o Firefox, por exemplo) havia possibilidade disso via configurações, mas essa opção foi removida nas versões mais atuais.

Logo, pensar em usar pop-up e restringir seus recursos é algo desencorajado. Se quer usá-lo, tem que usar sem se preocupar se o usuário irá redimensioná-lo, movê-lo, ver o endereço etc. O importante mesmo é o conteúdo da janela, e isso você pode manipular como quiser.

Inicialmente essas opções pretendiam funcionar como padrão em todos os navegadores, mas alguns fabricantes acharam que o desenvolvedor/programador não deveria ter total controle sobre a janela, logo a maioria dos navegadores ignoram algumas opções, como é o caso do `resizable` e `location`. Basicamente, o que restou padrão e funcional em todos os navegadores foram as propriedades `width`, `height` (que não precisa do `px`, pois o valor já é em pixels), `top` e `left`.

Além do que, da forma que está abrindo a pop-up, sem a interação do usuário, a mesma será bloqueada nativamente pelo navegador, e o usuário teria que autorizar pop-ups na página.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme descrito [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features), só liste os parâmetros a serem habilitados. Ou seja, remova `location` e `resizable`.